# CMMotionManager updateinterval not set

Tags: ios, objective-c, cmmotionmanager

I'm using the CMMotionManager to gather accelerometer data. I am trying to set the update interval to every half second with the following:

```
[_motionManager setDeviceMotionUpdateInterval:.5];
[_motionManager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init]
                                     withHandler:^(CMAccelerometerData *accelerometerData, NSError *error) {
                                         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                             [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(update:) withObject:accelerometerData waitUntilDone:NO];
                                         });}];
```

yet I receive updates far more frequently than every half second. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wasn't setting the update interval for accelerometer itself.

```
[_motionManager setAccelerometerUpdateInterval:.5];
```